# Retrofit sample request

Tags: android, retrofit2

Is possibile to do a simple GET Request without adding Query "key=value", but only value?

like this: http://localhost:3000/users?5000

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible. It depends your get method from your server. We can't see what's inside your server, because is local.

Comment: My server is a sample deployd app (deployd.com). 
So i have a set of default API. For example, to search inside a post table, this is the query

/posts?{"likes": {"$gt": 10}}

so the value is a json string. I create the string a runtime but, if i use @Query annotation with empty value, the query becames

/posts?={"likes": {"$gt": 10}}

and it's wrong from what deployd server accepts

Comment: In retrofit terms and regarding your question, you can. You should check how to implement your server. Maybe you should remove query annotation since you are not using it, is empty.